# DirectX Has SetTechnique Can You Do Something Similar In OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl

DirectX has SetTechnique function that you can use to set which technique in the shader will be used.

Does OpenGL have something like this?

I know my way around glsl fairly decent. But I'm just wishing I can do techniques like I could in HLSL.

Comment: "*DirectX has SetTechnique function*" No it doesn't. D3DX, which is a *separate* library from the rest of D3D, has this function. D3DX is a library that sits *on top of* D3D; it's not actually part of Direct3D or HLSL.

Comment: sorry i'll phrase things better next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to the D3DX library for OpenGL. There are no GLSL "techniques", "passes", and so forth.